# Exception Handling in ASP.NET Web API giving me errors after HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

So here is one of my actions.

```
public Customers GetCustomer(int id)
{
    var customer = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

    if (customer == null)
        throw new HttpRequestException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    return customer;
}
```

This part of the code

```
throw new HttpRequestException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

throws the following error

> cannot convert from 'System.Net.HttpStatusCode' to 'String'

Also, in one of my other methods, same error is being thrown on the following.

```
throw new HttpRequestException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

This is an Api controller and I am not sure why these errors are being thrown. I looked up the syntax on the microsft website and it seems to be correct. It can be seen here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for is `HttpResponseException` and not `HttpRequestException`. If so, you can do it as below:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

This works, because as you can see in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.httpresponseexception?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-6.0), there is a constructor for that class that takes one parameter of type `HttpStatusCode`. On the other hand, as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception?view=net-6.0), this is not true for `HttpRequestException`.